# Pipe Get-ADGroupMember results into ADO RecordSet

Tags: powershell, active-directory, ado, recordset

Looking for a way to pipe the results of a `Get-ADGroupMember` query directly to an ADO Recordset.  The code I have:

```
$group = "myADgroupName"
Get-ADGroupMember $group | select-object "name" | Export-Csv -Path C:\test\$group.csv -Encoding ascii -NoTypeInformation
```

Will return a list of computer objects, and other groups, that are members of the ad group `myADgroupName` and export it to a csv file successfully.

But I'm having trouble finding how to capture the query results into some kind of container I can use later in the script.

I've tried:

```
$rsMembers = new-Object -COMObject ADODB.Recordset
$rsMembers.open
Get-ADGroupMember $comp | select-object "name" | $rsMembers
```

.. Which returns the error:

```
Expressions are only allowed as the first element of a pipeline
```

And also:

```
$rsMembers | Get-ADGroupMember $comp | select-object "name"
```

.. Which returns the error:

```
Can't validate empty parameter
```

And also:

```
$rsMembers = Get-ADGroupMember $group | select-object "name"
```

... none of which work.  Searched the interwebs high and low for answers, without success. Any assistance is appreciated!

Comment: Please format your code

Comment: What do you want to do with the results later? Just store the results in a variable: `$results = Get-ADGroupMember $group | select-object "name"` Or even better yet, don't get rid of properties on the objects at all: `$results = Get-ADGroupMember $group`

Comment: Thanks EB.. I'd like to iterate the returned list and write each line to a database (MSSQL).  Would I use foreach($result in $results) ?

Comment: Yes you could do that. Then use $result.Name to get the name to create your query.

Comment: @BobLochen `$RSMembers.Open` is a method. It should be called like this `$RSMembers.Open(Variant, Variant, CursorTypeEnum, LockTypeEnum, int)`. You will not be able to add anything until a connection is established. Given we do not know anything about your database, we cannot fill this in for you. After you have your connection established you should do something like this `Get-ADGroupMember $comp | select-object "name" | foreach-object { $rsmembers.AddNew($_) }`. Because you're using a ComObject you will not be able to pipe things to it directly.

Comment: Thanks again EB and thanks Shawn... I'm able to iterate the collection now.